# In Android Textview within a Scrollview, not displaying all the text(which it gets from strings.xml)

Tags: android

I am developing a game and need a popup for the rules. I write the text in the string.xml file and display in a textview within a Scrollview, but all the Text is not getting displayed. Only the last few lines of the text is getting displayed. Please help me!!

Here is the layout popup xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dialogbg1"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/howto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rule"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
        android:id="@+id/rules"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:outlineProvider="paddedBounds" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/done"
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#fffff7f4"
    android:background="@drawable/buttbg1"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

and the "rule" variable in the strings.xml file

```
<string name="rule">Rules to play Mancala!!!\n\nMancala is an ancient family of board games, and there are numerous variants.\n
    This is a version of the basic game, known as two-rank Mancala and also known as Kalah.\n
    1.The Mancala board is made up of two rows of six holes, or pits, each.\n\n
    2.Four playing pieces are placed in each of the 12 holes.\n\n
    3.Each player has a store to the right side of the Mancala board.\n\n
    4.The game begins with one player picking up all of the pieces in any one of the holes on his side.\n\n
    5.Moving counter clockwise, the player deposits one of the stones in each hole until the stones run out.\n\n
    6.If you run into your own store, deposit one piece in it. If you run into your opponent\'s store, skip it.\n\n
    7.If the last piece you drop is in your own store, you get a free turn.\n\n
    8.If the last piece you drop is in an empty hole on your side, you capture that piece and any pieces in the hole directly opposite.\n\n
    9.Always place all captured pieces in your store.\n\n
    10.The game ends when all six spaces on one side of the Mancala board are empty.\n\n
    11.The player who still has pieces on his side of the board when the game ends captures all of those pieces.\n\n
    12.Count all the pieces in each store. The winner is the player with the most pieces.</string>
```

I'm not able to figure out why all the text is not getting displayed. only text from 4 is getting displayed. If I change the layout screensize, then it gets displayed from 3. Please help me!!!

Comment: show your output screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop your line android:layout_gravity="center" from TextView.

Comment: It is strange. Are you sure you deleted `android:layout_gravity="center"` from TextView, not from ScrollView?
By the way, delete `android:layout_weight="1"` from your Button.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:maxLines="50"` in your `<TextView />` tag. This will make your TextView to add maximum 50 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your TextView Tag Use :

```
android:layout_gravity="top"
```